# Butterworth Lowpass Filter

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am not getting the desired output, it is cutting off the lower freq. no matter if I set it to 'low' or 'high'.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def butter_filter(data, butterCutoffFreq, order=1):
    b, a = signal.butter(order, butterCutoffFreq, 'low', analog=True)
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

"""
    White noise
"""
N = 1024
dt = np.float64(1)
y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=N)
t = np.arange(start=0, stop=N, step=dt)
butterCutoffFreq = 0.5 * 1/dt

amps = np.fft.rfft(y)
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(y.size, dt)
#plt.plot(freqs, np.abs(amps), color='b')

ampsFiltered = butter_filter(y, butterCutoffFreq)
ampsFiltered = np.fft.rfft(ampsFiltered)

plt.plot(freqs, np.abs(ampsFiltered), color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what is `dt`? Is `yWhitenoise` the same as `y`?

Comment: @Dan: fixed, tnx!

Comment: Have you tried varying values for `dt`? Maybe random noise at 1Hz intervals doesn't have nice properties. See if changing the frequency to something significantly higher makes the chart appear more low pass?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is whith the param `analog=True` remove it and it will work.

`lfilter()` can only use a digital filter. It doesn't make sense to filter a digital signal (your white noise assumed regularly sampled) with an analog filter.